# Schedule a deployment on Heroku

Tags: heroku, deployment

I have a simple app on Heroku. I'd like to launch the deployment automatically everynight. Is it possible to have something like a CRON to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could schedule something locally, but there is no Heroku tool for automatically deploying on a schedule each night, no.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a continuous integration (CI) tool like CircleCI to schedule and automate deployment to Heroku. It's a separate tool, and is more complex than just a CRON job, but it will allow you to deploy to many different environments, run test, and give you more fine control over your deployments.